# JQ get names of lists containing specific property value

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I have json file with infrastructure description. Simplified it for pasting here

```
{
  "vms": [
    {
      "vm01": [
        {
          "relevant": "true"
        }
      ],
      "vm02": [
        {
          "relevant": "false"
        }
      ],
      "vm03": [
        {
          "relevant": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need JQ statement for getting VM names (such as vm01, vm03) which have "relevant" key set to "true"

`jq '.vms[] | select(.[].relevant == "true" )| keys'` 
returns error (Cannot index array with string "relevant")

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can write such a query:

```
.vms[] | to_entries[] | select(any(.value[]; .relevant == "true")).key
```

We want to select the vms where any of its values have a `relevant` key set to `"true"`.

In your example: `.vms[] | select(.[].relevant == "true" )| keys`
You're attempting to go through all the values of the `vm` objects (which all happened to be arrays). You would have needed to do `select(.[][].relevant ...)` but at that point, you should be using the `any/2` filter.